# @DbLookup missing value when different document has value and null

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I have a view with 8 document, with the first and fourth document has value in particular Field, others are null. Normally I can get all eight documents when

```
@DbLookup(db, view, key, "field has value")
```

and output 1'value,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
but I got only six elements when i switch the field to another one which several document's field is null.

```
@DbLookup(db, view, key, "field some document is null")
```

and output 1,,4,,, losing two "" empty values.

Why does it only returns six value? I know that to avoid this can be done by adding select condition in view, is there an other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, see if you can use an @DbColumn.  With that, you should return something like:

```
"value1", "", "", "value4", "", "", "", ""
```

Don't do any @Trim on it, otherwise, you'll only get an array of:

```
"value1", "value4"
```